# Is there a shortcut for switching panels in PyCharm 3.4.1?

Tags: pycharm, code-navigation

If i'm currently editing the `db/transaction.py` file, line 158 (on the left), and would like to switch to the right panel (to edit the `admin/404.html`), is there a shortcut that allows me to do this?

I'd like to exclude right from the start the `Navigate > File` shortcut (`Ctrl+ Shift + R` - in my binding conf), because that requires me to type the name of a file, and to choose from a list, if too many files match. I just want to go to the inactive panel, on the active tab.

I'm also no wiz with the macros, and i couldn't get one working. If there's a way to do it with macros, i'm all ears.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Window | Editor Tabs | Goto Next Splitter`
- `Window | Editor Tabs | Goto Previous Splitter`

**P.S.**
Keyboard shortcuts can be assigned/changed at `Settings | Keymap`